# Why Can't I Retrieve a Public Property from PreviousPage?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, postback

I am trying to achieve what is described [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6c3yckfw.aspx#Anchor_3) under **Getting Public Property Values from the Source Page**.

After reading these SO questions:

[How to Persist Variable on Postback](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/222999/how-to-persist-variable-on-postback)

[How to pass values across the pages in ASP.net without using Session](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14956027/how-to-pass-values-across-the-pages-in-asp-net-without-using-session)

I have come to the conclusion that it seems to be impossible to do this (retrieve a public property from the `PreviousPage` variable).

---

Here is my attempt:

#### In source page code-behind (SourcePage.aspx.cs):

```
public MyClass PublicProperty { get; set; }
```

#### In target source code (TargetPage.aspx):

```
<%@ PreviousPageType VirtualPath="~/SourcePage.aspx" %>
```

#### In target page code-behind:

```
TextBox1.Text = PreviousPage.PublicProperty.PoNumber;
```

From an event handler in `SourcePage.aspx.cs`, I am calling (tried with and without 2nd parameter):

```
Server.Transfer("~/TargetPage.aspx", true);
```

But of course, before the page is actually transferred to, `Page_Load` is called in `SourcePage.aspx.cs`, and so `PublicProperty` is reset, and once the server reaches `TargetPage.aspx.cs`, `PreviousPage.PublicProperty` is equal to `null`.

---

My question is, is there any way at all of getting this to work? If not, why is this suggested as a method on `MSDN`? Does this work with other versions of ASP, or am I just doing something wrong?

Many thanks for your time and any advice you can give

Comment: is behavior same in `server.transfer` vs `response.redirect`? If it is ever bound to work, it would with `server.transfer`

Comment: @T.S. Yes I get the same result. I tried `Response.Redirect` first, but the article I linked suggests using `Transfer` so I'm assuming that is the correct way (but who knows with these MSDN articles!)

Comment: I was thinking that there is NO WAY `response.redirect` would work. Make sure that there is no any special code that clears those properties. Put debuggerinfo  into properties and see where do they get cleared.

Comment: Try to call this `TextBox1.Text = PreviousPage.PublicProperty.PoNumber;` on `init`. This is where your best chance to get the value. Also, try to create simple property `public int A {get { return 5;}}` and see if you get that value.